# Is is possible to do an HTTP multi-part form POST using IBM Sterling B2B Integrator?

Tags: http, integrator

The documentation [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/sb2bi/v5r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.svcs_adpts_a_l.doc/HTTP_Client_POST_svc.html) describes how to setup HTTP POST for this system, but it doesn't describe if or how to setup form variables in general and form file uploads specifically. My goal is to integrate with a website that accepts files as form POSTS, and I'm not even sure it's possible.

Can IBM Sterling Integrator be configured to make a HTTP multi-part form POST with file uploads?

Answer (score 3):

I recently had this issue also i had to do it with an XLST translation of the incoming xml

In the xlst you specify the following:

```
<xsl:output method="text" media-type="multipart/form-data" />
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I had trouble figuring out how to do this as well. I was just looking to do a simple HTTP POST via BPML.  Assigned my data to a temp node in the process data, did a XML Encoder, then XSLT Service.  Seems crazy you have to do that, but I can't figure out a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I created a JavaTask Service to solved, for me worked very well, look in github repository a simple example, in my github repository I've a example.